# what "Create a new DNS record for the server FQDN" means?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm trying to setup DirectAccess in Windows server 2012 R2, I'm following the step-by-step of this page
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/01/06/step-by-step-enabling-directaccess-in-windows-server-2012.aspx

In the step 2, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to help.  Sorry I did not see this sooner.

1.On the internal network DNS server: On the Start screen, type dnsmgmt.msc, and then press ENTER.

2.In the left pane of the DNS Manager console, expand the forward lookup zone for your domain. Right click the domain, and click New Host (A or AAAA).

3.In the New Host dialog box, In the IP address box: 
◦ In the Name (uses parent domain name if blank) box, enter the DNS name for the network location server website (this is the name that the DirectAccess clients use to connect to the network location server).

◦ Enter the IPv4 or IPv6 address of the network location server, and then click Add Host, and then click OK.

4.In the New Host dialog box: 
◦ In the Name (uses parent domain name if blank) box, enter the DNS name for the web probe (the name for the default web probe is directaccess-webprobehost).

◦ In the IP address box, enter the IPv4 or IPv6 address of the web probe, and then click Add Host.

◦ Repeat this process for directaccess-corpconnectivityhost and any manually created connectivity verifiers.

5.In the DNS dialog box, click OK, and then click Done.

I will also modify the post to provide better direction.

Cheers,

AB